# Problem installing a Python program from GitHub

Tags: python, json, windows, github, pip

I am trying to install the [MQTT simulator](https://github.com/DamascenoRafael/mqtt-simulator).

I have python v3.3.10 installed in my computer. I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjF9wmA4ik4&t=398s) between 1:48 and 5.43, so now I have a folder in my desktop called python_project, inside of which there is a folder called venv.

I have downloaded the mqtt-simulator-master from git hub and put it inside of python_project and copied the contents of mqtt-simulator-master onto python project itself. I have activated the virtual environment as `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\python_project>.\venv\Scripts\activate`.

Then I have written in the CMD  `C:\Users\Jaime\Desktop\python_project>python3 -m venv venv`
which didn't have any visible output.

The next line was `source venv/bin/activate`, which resulted in an error, which said that source is an unrecognized command.

Then I wrote `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`. This gave me an output with the warning

> DEPRECATION: paho-mqtt is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py
> install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the
> 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour
> change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option.
> Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559

and the output `Successfully installed paho-mqtt-1.5.0`

However, if I write `python3 mqtt-simulator/main.py`, i get the following error:

> File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\python_project\mqtt-simulator\main.py",
> line 3, in 
> from simulator import Simulator   File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\python_project\mqtt-simulator\simulator.py",
> line 2, in 
> from topic import TopicAuto   File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\python_project\mqtt-simulator\topic.py", line
> 6, in 
> import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paho'

I need some tips on how to make this work since I am clueless about what to do.

Comment: source is a linux command, 
if you are running this in CMD, use the dot instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've followed the same instructions I'm able to sucessfully run the git files. I'm guessing you messing up env's like u may installing requiremnts in different env and may running code in different environment. Do one thing

**Debugging steps may help you:**

1. Take a fresh cmd don't create any environment
2. run `pip3 install paho-mqtt==1.5.0`
3. Then go to folder or run like `python3 Desktop\python_project\mqtt-simulator\main.py` (assuming cmd at `C:\Users\Me\`)

see what you will get.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At last the program is running. Can you please tell me if your ouptut looks like this?`Starting: oximeters/2 ...
Starting: oximeters/3 ...
Starting: oximeters/4 ...
Starting: oximeters/5 ...
Starting: oximeters/6 ...
Starting: oximeters/7 ...
Starting: oximeters/8 ...
Starting: oximeters/9 ...
Starting: oximeters/10 ...
Starting: alerts/2 ...
Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):` It seems that I am getting another error now

Comment: I'vent run the complete program...I able to see what's wrong with importing...So I've told you steps...It's differnt error post differnt question or update the same on the current question